# creating multiple views in the same script in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view

I have a table that is the result of an INNER JOIN and then to that table I have to a apply a bunch of queries, so at the end the whole code in SQL is really big and in the future (and that's the main problem) I will have problems to understand what did I do.

So for this reason I am considering the possibility of creating views, so in each step I have a view created and I know what does each one of the queries.

So with that goal I started to use IF ELSE statements to create views if they dont' exist etc. but I'm stumbling with a lot of errors and problems.

First of all, this is the way I'm creating a view with the IF statement:

```
-- This portion of code is common in all the views
IF NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM sys.views
    WHERE Name = 'NAME_OF_THE_VIEW'
)
BEGIN

    EXEC('CREATE VIEW NAME_OF_THE_VIEW AS SELECT 1 as Val')

END

GO
ALTER VIEW NAME_OF_THE_VIEW
AS

-- Here I put the query of the view

SELECT *
FROM table_1
```

When I execute this code it works, but the SQL Server Management Studio underlines "NAME_OF_THE_VIEW" in the ALTER VIEW statement and when I hover the mouse it says: Invalid object name 'NAME_OF_THE_VIEW'. I don't understand why if there's a supposed error it still works.

The other problem is that when I introduce more code like the code above in order to create other views in the same script, the whole ALTER VIEW statement is underlined and when I hover this message appears; Incorrect syntax: 'ALTER VIEW' must be the only statement in the batch.

So the question is: hoy can I put everything in the same script, where I can create views to avoid doing a lot of subqueries, and without getting this errors? The SQL-Server version is 15.

Comment: Run the SQL... You won't get the error. That's intellisense saying that the `VIEW` doesn't exist, because at the time of *it* parsing the SQL is doesn't, and the `VIEW` is being created in a separate scope; so it has no idea it's being created. TL;DR: The SQL you've provided works fine: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c0f56b99b5c61373f8805ad236bccc8b)

Comment: if you add more after what you've shown us, you'll need another "GO" to keep your "ALTER VIEW..." in its own batch.  (Or else use EXEC('...') which always executes in a separate batch).

Comment: the problem is the red underline extends to other parts of the code so eventually I will be in a situation where everything is underlined and I will get a real error and I will not be able to detect the problem. And also, I don't understand why it works and at the same time it underlines and advise of syntax errors.

Comment: IntelliSense reports possible errors as suggestions, not a certain runtime error. IntelliSense does not consider dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Miquel No, it's just that the Intellisense for a session doesn't update the way that you think it would, but that doesn't affect the compiler at all.  If it bothers you, just create a new session and see if the lines are there.

Comment: yeah it's really annoying, is there a way to block this intelliSense thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So the question is: hoy can I put everything in the same script, where I can create views to avoid doing a lot of subqueries, and without getting this errors?

There's no need to check for existence of the view.  Just CREATE OR ALTER VIEW

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW NAME_OF_THE_VIEW
AS

-- Here I put the query of the view

SELECT *
FROM table_1

GO

CREATE OR ALTER VIEW NAME_OF_THE_OTHER_VIEW
AS

-- Here I put the query of the view

SELECT *
FROM table_1
```

Comment: And I would be able to replicate this many times in the same script?

Comment: Seperated by `GO`, yes.

Comment: In  which position should the "GO" be placed?

Comment: On a line by itself separating the script into separate batches.  CREATE OR ALTER VIEW must be the only statement in a batch.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, very good and simple solution for all.